# beforeunload event hide the alert message in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I have catched the event "beforeunload" but I want to do some custom actions and not show the alert message that is shown by default, I want to hide the alert box.

```
componentDidMount() {
   window.addEventListener("beforeunload", ev) => {
      ev.preventDefault();
      this.customExit(ev);
      return null;
   }
}
```

How can I hide the alert box?

Comment: This answer may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/20067494/801544

Comment: You can't.  This is one of the things provided by browsers to keep the user in control, not the page.

Comment: Any syntax error `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", ev) => {` here?

Comment: Can I then sumulate the event of pressing on the "stay on page" button?

Comment: @georgiana_e No.  The user has requested to leave the page for whatever reason.  This alert is the only thing the browser will allow you to use to inform them that they may lose work if they leave now.  You cannot do anything to prevent them leaving, or interact with the alert programattically in any other way.