# Angular 12 - 'onbeforeunload' event not fired

Tags: angular

I want to trigger event on page refresh.

I try all these methods but none of them worked. When I reload the page, nothing happens. What can I try to resolve this?

```
//1
@HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
unloadHandler(event: any) {
  alert(1)
}
//2
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
beforeUnloadHandler(event: any) {
  alert(2)
}
//3
window.onbeforeunload = function(event)
{
    return confirm("Confirm refresh");
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [window.onbeforeunload not displaying the alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067472/window-onbeforeunload-not-displaying-the-alert-box)

Comment: Thanks on the response! it's also dose nothing. maybe it's issue in angular?

Comment: The question I linked just shows that the browser blocks alerts in `beforeunload` events. So in order to test if it's working, you should not use alerts. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using the `ngOnDestroy()` callback on the `AppComponent`? Your code will be triggered when the app is unloaded.